# I'm trying to read from a json file in my ejs template

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, express

I've got my data.json file and I want to read from the data stored in the file to './views/modules/header.ejs'. Ideally the data in the json file will be available to all modules in my project.

I'm using expressJs files and want to print the information from my json file to my web page. I've been able to load the data in my app.js file using the code below:

```
//import json
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
let jsonData = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8');
let data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
console.log(data.menu);
```

This is the content stored in the menu array:

```
"menu": [
    {
        "title": "Home",
        "link": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Location",
        "link": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Facilities",
        "link": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Building details",
        "link": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Floor plans",
        "link": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Contact",
        "link": ""
    }
],
```

This is my header.ejs file:

```
<ul class="menu-list">
    <% for(var i=0; i < data.menu.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%= data.data.menu[i].title %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

I believe I'm missing a statement on my ejs file which will call the data. Thanks for your help in advance.

this is my index.js file looks like.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Bank' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: <li><%= data.menu[i].title %></li>

Comment: I'm getting a data is not defined error, I accidentally had that second '.data' in the call. I believe it's because the json needs to be imported some how.

Comment: Now run correctly

Comment: that didn't work, my error is: "data is not defined"

Comment: Can we connect skype

Comment: google hangouts? jas@unruly.world :)

Comment: I sent request at google handouts

Comment: I havent seen it, whats yours?

Comment: mahesh.bhatnagar1990@gmail.com my gmail address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code use in router file

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const fs = require('fs');
  let jsonData = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
  let data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  let dataRecord = data.data;
  let dataRecordMenu=dataRecord.menu;
res.render('index', { title: 'Bank',data:dataRecordMenu });
});
```

That code use in view file

```
<ul class="menu-list">
      <% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
          <li><%= data[i].title %></li>
      <% } %>
  </ul>
```